Question about RRC Filter Parameters in GNU Radio's QPSK Example
I'm learning about pulse shaping and matched filtering using an RRC filter.
GNU Radio has a good tutorial on this in the QPSK tutorial.
I understand the parameters of the RRC filter taps, but in the GNU Radio example QPSK_stage6 they use a very strange value:
firdes.root_raised_cosine(nfilts, nfilts, 1.0/float(sps), 0.35, 11*sps*nfilts)

where nfilts = 32, sps = 4, and samp_rate = 32e3.
How does this value work? Is it some type of normalization?
As I understand it, the form should be:
firdes.root_raised_cosine(gain, sample_rate, symbol_rate, alpha, num_filter).

So how does this convert to the previous one?
